# How to run TTask multiple times in parallel?

Tags: delphi

I've a simple method that use `TTask` method to perform a long time operation calling a datasnap server.

The method below does the job:

```
procedure AssignPhoto(PhotoName, Folder: string; Image: TImage);
var
   Server: TSMClient;
   Size: Int64;
begin
  Server := TSMClient.Create(dmDados.DSRestConnection1);
  Size := 0;
  TTask.Run(
  procedure
  var
    PhotoStream: TStream;
  begin
    { 1. Long time operation calls datasnap to get a stream }
    PhotoStream := Server.DownloadFile(PhotoName, Folder, Size);

    { 2. Get the result in the UI Thread and display the picture }
    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Image.Picture.LoadFromStream(PhotoStream);
      FreeAndNil(Server);
    end);

  end);
end;
```

As you can see, this just call a datasnap server to get a `TStream` picture and load it into a `TImage` that was passed as a parameter.

The method works well, however, the problem is: if I call this method twice it doesn't work.

I call this method twice to load user's profile photo and user's id photo as the code below suggest.

```
  if FUrlProfile <> '' then
    AssignPhoto(FUrlProfile, PROFILE_PHOTO, imgProfile);
  if FUrlDoc <> '' then
    AssignPhoto(FUrlDoc, DOC_PHOTO, imgDoc);
```

This opens a form and load the pictures in two `TImage` components.

1. The first time I open the form it works pretty well;
2. When I try to open the form again. The second time I try to open the form I get the error:

`ENetHTTPRequestException with message 'Error adding header: (87) Incorrect Parameter'`

I know that,

1. If I load only one picture it works pretty well all the time.
2. If I open the form, close and open again really fast it causes the error.
3. If I open the form, close, wait for a while and open it again it doesn't cause the error. It seams it needs to get something done before starting the `procedure` again.

So the problem is that it seams I can't call the `TTask` method multiple times. Maybe, am I missing something?

Comment: I edited the question, Server is a datasnap server that gets a `TStream` from a remote computer. But the method works fine, it doesn't work when running in the background.

Comment: It's clear what it is, what was important to know is whether it was declared locally or whether it was a class member or global variable.  We see now that it is a local variable, thank you.

Comment: Which delphi version?

Comment: You appear to be sharing a `TDSRestConnection` between multiple threads.  This immediately feels like a mistake - multiple threads should each have their own connections.

Comment: Got it, but each time the method is called it creates another `Server` instance. If this doesn't work, should I maybe create the `DSRestConnection` at runtime? Obs: The `DSRestConnection` is inside a `DataModule`

Comment: You create a new `TSMClient` instance each time, but you pass each one the same `TDSRestConnection` instance.  So, yes, create a new connection for each thread.

Comment: Dont forget to free the stream after you’ve loaded the picture...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@J... was correct in his comment. The problem was because I was using the same `TDSRestConnection` in multiple threads.

So, creating a `TDSRestConnection` each time the method was created is the solution.

```
procedure AssignPhoto(PhotoName, Folder: string; Image: TImage);
var
  Server: TSMClient;
  Size: Int64;  
  DSRestConnection: TDSRestConnection;
begin
  DSRestConnection := GetConnection; // Creates a new TDSRestConnection
  Server := TSMClient.Create(DSRestConnection);
  Size := 0;
  TTask.Run(
  procedure
  var
    PhotoStream: TStream;
  begin
    { 1. Long time operation calls datasnap to get a stream }
    PhotoStream := Server.DownloadFile(PhotoName, Folder, Size);

    { 2. Get the result in the UI Thread and display the picture }
    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Image.Picture.LoadFromStream(PhotoStream);
      FreeAndNil(Server);
    end);

  end);
end;

function GetConnection: TDSRestConnection;
begin
  Result := TDSRestConnection.Create(nil);
  Result.Host := SERVER_HOST;
  Result.Port := SERVER_PORT;
end;
```

Comment: Conceptually, a connection encapsulates a serialized bidirectional stream.  If you consider two threads using the same stream, it's a bit like two people answering the same phone at the same time and each of them trying to have a conversation with the person on the other end simultaneously.  Because no single thread owns the stream, each of them can send bytes  belonging to their own messages which end up mixed up with the bytes from the other.  The receiver has no idea which byte belongs to which message and it all ends up a mess.

Comment: Yeah, this looks a bit leaky. I wonder why connection and server are created outside the task.

Comment: Should I create everyting inside the `TTask`. What about the `PhotoStream` var? Do I need to free it after the process is done and is it ok being created inside the `TTask`?

Comment: Inside the task would be much better, yes.  You need to ensure that things are deterministically freed, whether things go wrong or not.  That means `try/finally` blocks.  Creating in one thread and freeing in another usually has ways to fail badly - I would avoid that.  Create and free in the same thread, guard with try/finally, use `Queue` instead of `Synchronize` with a `TEvent` to signal (with timeout) the task that processing is complete and the object can be destroyed.  If the operation times out, for whatever reason, the `Queue`d work also needs to handle that case.